# Pandas pivot with duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert this dataframe:

```
| project  | id | problem | result |
|----------|----|---------|--------|
| Project1 | 1  | P1      | True   |
| Project1 | 1  | P2      | True   |
| Project1 | 1  | P3      | False  |
| Project1 | 1  | P4      | True   |
| Project1 | 1  | P5      | NA     |
| Project2 | 1  | P1      | True   |
| Project2 | 1  | P2      | False  |
| Project2 | 1  | P3      | False  |
| Project2 | 1  | P4      | NA     |
| Project2 | 1  | P5      | True   |
```

to this:

```
| project  | id | P1   | P2    | P3    | P4   | P5   |
|----------|----|------|-------|-------|------|------|
| Project1 | 1  | True | True  | False | True | NA   |
| Project2 | 1  | True | False | False | NA   | True |
```

I tried pivot method:

```
df.pivot(index=["project", "id"], columns="problem", values="result")
```

But, I am getting the error: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

How can I convert the dataframe?

Comment: use `pivot_table` and define a `aggfunc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with custom lambda function:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=["project", "id"], 
                    columns="problem", 
                    values="result", 
                    aggfunc=lambda x: x.any() if x.notna().all() else np.nan)
print (df)
problem        P1     P2     P3    P4    P5
project  id                                
Project1 1   True   True  False  True   NaN
Project2 1   True  False  False   NaN  True
```

If need working with `NaN`s and boolean `True/False` is possible use [Nullable Boolean data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
df['result'] = df['result'].astype('boolean')

df = df.pivot_table(index=["project", "id"], 
                    columns="problem",
                    values="result", 
                    aggfunc=lambda x: x.any() if x.notna().all() else np.nan)
print (df)
problem        P1     P2     P3    P4    P5
project  id                                
Project1 1   True   True  False  True  <NA>
Project2 1   True  False  False  <NA>  True
```

If possible output `True/False` only:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=["project", "id"], 
                    columns="problem",
                    values="result", 
                    aggfunc='any')
print (df)
problem        P1     P2     P3     P4     P5
project  id                                  
Project1 1   True   True  False   True  False
Project2 1   True  False  False  False   True
```

EDIT: In version pandas 1.3+ is possible use:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=["project", "id"], 
                    columns="problem",
                    values="result", 
                    aggfunc=lambda x: x.any(skipna=True))
print (df)
```

Comment: Thanks, what is `aggfunc='any'`? I couldn't find it in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

Comment: @EmreSülün - It is hidden here - [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html)

Comment: A note to myself after 1.5 years, I was using x.any(skipna=True) instead of the lambda function as it was producing the same results and faster but there was [a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/40585) in it which was fixed in pandas version 1.3.